# convert a DTO to Entity with using mapper class

Tags: java, spring, dto

I have a Entity class something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Website {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String url;
    public Website() {
     //Constructor 
      //getters and setters
    }
```

here is the DTO class:

```
public class WebsiteDto { 
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String url;
    public WebsiteVo() {

      //Constructor 
      //getters and setters
    }
```

I have the WebsiteMapper something like this:

```
@Component 
public class WebsiteMapper {

    public List<WebsiteDto> getWebsiteList() {
        return repository.findAll().stream().map(w -> {
            WebsiteDto dto = new WebsiteVo(w.getId(), w.getName(), w.getUrl());
            return dto;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I also have Repository Interface:

```
public interface WebsiteRepository extends JpaRepository<Website, Integer> {
}
```

I want now to convert DTO to entity using my class WebsiteMapper. Because I did the conversion in this class. How I can do it?

Comment: What is WebsiteMapper? Does this class injects WebsiteRepository?
Why WebsiteMapper is @Component?

Comment: take a look here https://mapstruct.org/

Comment: @Lemmy WebsiteMapper Provides methods to convert a DTO to a Entity and vice versa.

Comment: Take a look at Mapstruct or ModelMapper libraries.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `BeanUtils` provided by spring `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils`,  something like this

```
public List<WebsiteDto> getWebsiteList() {
        return repository.findAll().stream().map(w -> {
            WebsiteDto dto = new WebsiteVo();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(w, dto);  // copys all variables with same name and type
            return dto;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi I guess you wish to converting your entity to DTO. It's quite simple. Create static methods in your DTO class or any util class. The return type should be your DTO type.

e.g.

```
public class WebsiteDto {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public static WebsiteDto export(Website website) {
        // Return a new instance of your website DTO
        return new WebsiteDto(
                website.getId(),
                website.getName(),
                website.getUrl()
        );
    }

    public static List<WebsiteDto> export(List<Website> websites) {
        // Return a new instance of your website DTO list

        return websites.stream().map(website -> {
            return new WebsiteDto(
                website.getName(),
                website.getUrl()
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**NOTE** You can also convert your DTO to entity using similar method.

Comment: byteHungt3r. So I have on Interface class and one class that implement my Interface. I call the repository in the class and my Websitemapper too. I only need to call Websitemapper with @autowired

Comment: Your DTO object shouldn't contain the logic for transforming from Entity -> DTO, you should always have a transformer class in between. DTOs shouldn't contain logic, they should be simple model classes.